# XML Schema to validate each value in an NMTOKENS attribute list

Tags: xml, xsd, relaxng

Given this XML file:

```xml
<users blessed="phrogz alians">
  <user name="phrogz"  id="42" />
  <user name="lachtok" id="3"  />
  <user name="vielee"  id="5"  />
  <user name="alians"  id="17" />
</users>
```

...is it possible to create an XSD `key`/`keyref` style validation that ensures that each value in the the `blessed` list matches against an existing `user/@name`?

If this is not possible with XSD, is it possible with RelaxNG?

Comment: Similarly, is there a way to enforce uniqueness, i.e. prevent `blessed="phrogz phrogz phrogz"`? :)

Comment: Not possible in Relax NG syntax, but can be done with embedded schematron rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible with XSD 1.0. It's straightforward in XSD 1.1, of course, using assertions:

Uniqueness (if defined at the level of the users element):

```
<xsl:assert test="count(@blessed) = count(distinct-values(@blessed))"/>
```

Referential integrity (if defined at the level of the users element):

```
<xsl:assert test="every $t in data(@blessed) satisfies $t = user/@name"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your expertise and help. I feel honestly honored for you to have been the one to help me. :)